# Synching SharePoint 2013 List with Oracle

Tags: oracle, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm having an issue where a customer wants to populate a SharePoint 2013 List with a data from Oracle (using a query) and have that List automatically synched with the Oracle database daily.

From my understanding the External Content Type is just a direct view of the external database pulled in real-time to SharePoint? What if in the SharePoint the user adds more data for the External List? When the External List is refreshed, will the key/id relationship (if any) exist in the External List so that user entry will map to the correct External List entry (with the data from Oracle)?

How should I go about any Oracle data synchronization with any List in SharePoint automatically? What are the ways I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't exactly worked with External Content Types. But I did displayed SQL table into SharePoint using Visual WebPart. 
If you are allowed to deploy sandbox/farm code into your SharePoint Environment, than you can create a visual webpart and do sql query to your oracle database just like you would do with ado.net applications and display the result in your sharepoint page. You can create a asp.net gridview to do CRUD operations as well.

Answer (score 0):

View and modify data stored at an external database is an OOTB Feature of SharePoint. The Feature is called *BDC* and supports live CRUD operations. So there is no synchronization required.
There are plenty samples on the net. For oracle have a look to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff464424(v=office.14).aspx

or with a 3rd party tool:
http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/community/FAQs/BDLC/Pages/How-to-connect-SharePoint-list-with-Oracle-data.aspx